# Passing a comma (,) into the command line

Tags: shell, vba, batch-file, parameters, cmd

I have a string which I am passing into the command, the string contains multiple codes which are split up with a comma. When I pass this string through to the command line, it basically stops displaying text after the comma.

```vbnet
domainCodeList = "101, 102, 103, 104, 105"

'Now that we have populated the string with the possible domain codes, we now execute the batch file
strBatchName = SystemData.AppPath + "DetailedContacts.bat" & " " & domainCodeList
Shell strBatchName
```

When this is ran, the output I get in the command like is:

[image]

The code for my batch file is:

```
@echo off
echo %1
```

Any help on how I can pass commas to the command line would be great! Thanks
    pause

Comment: In your batch file, change `echo %1` to `echo %*`

Comment: Awesome, but say now I wanted to pass two arguments through, how can I choose between %1 and %2?

Comment: when you use `%*` you are saying pass all parameters from the command line, so you have to write your own code to parse each one. Use MC ND's answer below and then it's just %1 %2, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strBatchName = SystemData.AppPath + "DetailedContacts.bat" & " " & """" & domainCodeList & """"
```

Or

```
strBatchName = SystemData.AppPath + "DetailedContacts.bat" & " " & Chr(34) & domainCodeList & Chr(34)
```

Parameters with spaces or special characters in it need to be quoted.

From your batch file use %1 to retrieve the argument with quotes or use %~1 to retrieve the argument without quotes.